# How to mock Angular service properly? Karma Jasmine test: Expected spy service.getShipPhotos to have been called once. It was called 0 times

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am working with Angular 12 and Karma-Jasmine 4 and am testing to verify that the function getSingleShip is being called by the function retrieveShip, but the test result shows it has not been called at all.
I suspect the real service is being called instead of the mock.
How do I mock the service properly?

The below and similar tests that depend on mockShipsService.getSingleShip fail (Expected spy ShipsService.getSingleShip to have been called once. It was called 0 times.).

spec.ts:

```
 beforeEach(async () => {
    const spyShipServ = jasmine.createSpyObj('ShipsService', ['getSingleShip']);
    mockActivatedRoute = {
      snapshot: {
        paramMap: {
          get: () => { return "610a80fd485a6ad03b43b539" }
        }
      }
    }

    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(routes),
      ],
      declarations: [
        DetailedShipComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: ShipsService, useValue: spyShipServ },
        { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: mockActivatedRoute },
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
    mockShipsService = TestBed.inject(ShipsService) as jasmine.SpyObj<ShipsService>
    router = TestBed.inject(Router);
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DetailedShipComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });


  describe('retrieveShip', () => {
    it('should call getSingleShip once', () => {
      getSingleShipResponse = {
        _id: "610a80fd485a6ad03b43b539",
        name: "Sabrina",
        type: "cruise"
      };
      mockShipsService.getSingleShip.and.returnValue(of(getSingleShipResponse));

      component.retrieveShip("610a80fd485a6ad03b43b539");

      expect(mockShipsService.getSingleShip).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    })
  })
```

The above is done according to Angular docs here: [Testing services](https://angular.io/guide/testing-services)

component.ts:

```
  retrieveShip(shipId: string): void {
    this.shipsService.getSingleShip(shipId).subscribe({
      next: response => {
        this.ship = response;
      },
      error: err => this.errorMessage = err
    });
  }
```

service.ts:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ShipsService {
  readonly ROOT_URL: string = environment.ROOT_URL;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
  ) {
  }

  getSingleShip(shipId: string): Observable<Ship> {
    return this.http.get<Ship>(`${this.ROOT_URL}/ships/${shipId}`);
  }
}
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came to the following solution: Inject the real service and use callFake().

spec.ts:

```
beforeEach(async () => {
  await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [
      HttpClientTestingModule,
    ],
    declarations: [
      DetailedShipComponent
    ],
  })
    .compileComponents();
});

beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DetailedShipComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  service = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(ShipsService);
});

describe('retrieveShip', () => {
 it('should call getSingleShip once', waitForAsync(() => {
   spyOn(service, "getSingleShip").and.callFake(() => {
     return of(singleShipResponse);
   })

   component.retrieveShip("610a80fd485a6ad03b43b539");

   expect(service.getSingleShip).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
 }))
})
```

The tests pass now!

This is the video that gave me the idea:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l4oYN3TvKM4

Answer (score 0):

generally you provide a mocked service (to not get into real consequences, if services like these do for example HTTP calls, or not to mingle with other unit tests using the same service) and provide that mock. Then you spy on that mock, creating either an Object or just the spy, and give it the return value you'd expect. I'd say, you're 95% correct.

Also remember to fakeAsync and tick() asyncronous calls. If you return an of(element) (aka observable or promise) it doesn't count the call syncronously.

for example:

```
const spyShipServ: Partial<ShipsService> = { 
   public getSingleShip(shipId: string): Ship { return null; }

describe('retrieveShipComponent', () => {
  it('should call getSingleShip once', fakeAsync(() => {

    //you're not doing anything with the return, so and.returnValue isn't necessary here
    spyOn(spyShipServ, 'getSingleShip'); 

    component.retrieveShip("610a80fd485a6ad03b43b539");
    tick();
    expect(spyShipServ.getSingleShip).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  ))}
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the answer! Unfortunately, this didn't work, although you are right that I don't need the returnValue. In the end, this is how I solved it - injected the real service and used callFake() for the tests. I'll post the code in an answer.